# How can I persist sibling ui-views when changing state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

I have 2 `ui-view` directives in my application. One contains subnavigation and the other is the actual page content. My subnavigation is a tree structure, and when you click on an end node (or a leaf) should be the only time the content view gets updated. Whenever you click non-leaf nodes in the subnavigation, I would like the content view to stay the same while the subnavigation view changes.

What is happening is whenever I switch to a state that does not define one of the views, the view gets cleared out. I want it to stay how it was previous to me changing state. Has anyone accomplished this?

[image]

Code:

```
<!--NOTE THAT THESE ARE SIBLING ELEMENTS, NOT NESTED -->
<div id="subNav" ui-view="subNav"></div>
<div id="content" ui-view="content"></div>
```

Here is my route setup. Note that State1 only should update the `subnav` view and State2 should only update the `content` view.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('State1', {
    url: '/State1',
    views: {
      "subnav": { 
         templateUrl: "views/subnav.html",
         controller: "SubNavController"
      }
    }
  })
  .state('State2', {
    url: '/State2',
    views: {
      "content": { 
         template: "<p>State 2</p>"
      }
    }
  });
```

Here is a plnkr of what is is currently doing: http://plnkr.co/edit/TF7x5spB8zFLQPzrgZc9?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, that the way to go here is really very clear:

#### [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

#### [Nested States & Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

I am using this technique, in very similar scenario: left column is a list, right *(large area)* is a place for a detail. There is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0BJ09BxR7nG9kZDeEIv?p=preview)

The state def would be:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          '@' : {
            templateUrl: 'layout.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
          },
          'top@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.top.html',},
          'left@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.left.html',},
          'main@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.main.html',},
        },
      })
    .state('index.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
      })
    .state('index.list.detail', {
        url: '/:id',
        views: {
          'detail@index' : {
            templateUrl: 'detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl'
          },
        },
      })
```

So in our case, it could be like this:

1. the parent state would have a template for both states (layout) and also will inject the navbar
2. the child will just inject the view into main area

the Parent state:

```
.state('State1', {
    url: '/State1',
    views: {
      "bodyArea" { template: "body.thml"},
      "subnav@State1": { 
         templateUrl: "views/subnav.html",
         controller: "SubNavController"
      }
    }
})
```

So what we can see, the template for both states, the layout is defined on the `State1` as a view placed in "bodyArea".

The other view (original) is injected into that template, via absolute name "subnav@State1". I.e. 2 views defined for one parent state...

The Child state:

```
.state('State2', {
    parent: 'State1', // a child needs parent
    url: '/State2',
    views: {
      "content": { 
         template: "<p>State 2</p>"
      }
    }
})
```

Here, we just say, that State1 is parent of State2. That means, that the "content" target/anchor *(`ui-view="content"`)* must be part of the views defined in State1. The best place here would the "body.html"...

EXTEND: based on comments and [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TF7x5spB8zFLQPzrgZc9?p=preview) with some issues, I created its [updated version](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWyrx1O7WjhxNFPh2hK0?p=preview). Navigation to Main1 is broken (to be able to compare), but Main2 and Main3 are working.

- **Main2** is working because it has the similar def as `index` state
- **Main3** is on the other hand child of the `index` state

The absolute and relative naming in action should be clear from this snippet:

the index:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'layout.html'
      },
      'mainNav@index': {
        template: '<a ui-sref="Main1">Main1</a><br />'
                + '<a ui-sref="Main2">Main2</a><br />'
                + '<a ui-sref="Main3">Main3</a>'
      },
      'subNav@index' : {
        template: '<p>This is the sub navigation</p>'
      }, 
      'content@index': {
        template: '<p>This is the content</p>'
      }
    }
  })
```

the Main1 with issues

```
  .state('Main1', {
    url: '/Main1',
    views: {
      /*'mainNav': {

      },*/
      'subNav': {
        template: '<a ui-sref="Sub1">Sub1</a><a ui-sref="Sub2">Sub2</a>'
      },
      'content': {
        template: '<p>This is the content in Main1</p>'
      }
    }
  })
```

working states

```
  .state('Main2', {
    url: '/Main2',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'layout.html'
      },
      'mainNav@Main2': {
        template: '<a ui-sref="Main1">Main1</a><br />'
                + '<a ui-sref="Main2">Main2</a><br />'
                + '<a ui-sref="Main3">Main3</a>'
      },
      'subNav@Main2': {
        template: '<a ui-sref="Sub1">Sub for Main2</a>'
      },
      'content@Main2': {
        template: '<p>This is the content in Main2</p>'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('Main3', {
    parent: 'index',  // PARENT does the trick
    url: '/Main3',
    views: {
      'subNav': { // PARENT contains the anchor/target - relative name is enough
        template: '<a ui-sref="Sub1">Sub for Main3</a>'
      },
      'content': {
        template: '<p>This is the content in Main3</p>'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Radim. I have been trying to figure out how the syntax for the view names (like `detail@index`) works and I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I am putting together a Plunkr now and I'll link it here in a few.

Comment: Here is what I am having a problem with. Notice whenever you click 'Main1' everything disappears. I have tried using the `@` syntax in different ways but can't quitee figure out how to get this to work. http://plnkr.co/edit/TF7x5spB8zFLQPzrgZc9?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Radim, it is clearer now and I was able to get `Main1` to work after looking at your other examples. Is there any way to keep one of the views unaltered whenever you switch from one state to another? So whenever I switch from `Main2` to `Main3`, can I keep the content page the same until I click on something in the subnav section?

Comment: Yes, all that is possible, here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dz6ag35QZxxIj40xjy3m?p=preview. The content is defined in index for both mains (3,4) only if the submenu is selected - content is changed. Enjoy ui-router

Comment: @gwin003 well your only number 2.982.298.123.302.123 to have troubles with the view model... Which was a huge motivator in creating http://dotjem.github.io/angular-routing/... ;)

Comment: I tried to achieve the mentioned behavior of keeping the content persistent, and only changing it when selecting an entry in the submenu. It seems like you guys solved that problem, but the plunkr doesn't show that behavior.